# text size and div size is not adjusting in android phone by using jQuerymobile ...any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

i'm using jquery mobile ,here i'm using collapsible-set and there is two sub contents in my data-role="content" . In primary-content i have collapsible div's, and this primary content is taking 29% of the total width of the screen .But the problem is the size of the font and div size is not adjustable on android phone but it is working fine on tab.

```
  <html>
  <style>
  #nav
  {
  float: left;
  width: 29%;
   border:1px solid #a1a1a1;
  overflow: auto;


 }


  </style>


  <body>
   <div data-role="content-secondary" id="nav">
 <div  data-role="collapsible-set"  data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-             expanded-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" >
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a"  data-content-theme="a" >
            <h3 >Devices</h3>
                  <div  data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a">
                       <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"  data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
                <h3> Lights</h3>
                    <div  data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a">
                        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"  data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
                            <h3> Floor1</h3>
                                <div  data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a">
                                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a"  data-content-theme="a">
                                        <h3> Bed Room</h3>
                                            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-dividertheme="b">
                                                <li><a href=javascript:addText1()>BedRoom Light1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href=javascript:addText2()>BedRoom Light2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href=javascript:addText3()>BedRoom Light3</a></li>                                                   
                                                </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>




                                </body>
</html>
```

pleases share your experience here ...thanks

Comment: Dont post the same question twice! Wait and you'll get answer. possible duplicate of [text size and div size is not adjusting in android phone by using jQuerymobile .any suggestions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419528/text-size-and-div-size-is-not-adjusting-in-android-phone-by-using-jquerymobile)

Comment: when i tried to add my code it happened by mistake srr ....any one pls help me out

Comment: It's ok, pls delete this question.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/L9XwD/

Comment: yes it is...thank you very much and can we do same thing for division also?

Comment: but it is not working on android phone..    #nav .ui-btn-inner { font-size: 8px !important; }